# calling input value using jquery val() method not working after space in my MVC View?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Here is my code :

In My MVC View:

```
  @
  {
  var datefrom = Model.Vehicle.First().DateFrom.ToString("MMMM    yyyy")
  };
```

In my AjaxBeginForm:

```
    {
     <input type="hidden" id="vehicledatefrom" value=@datefrom/>
    }
```

My jquery:

```
          var datefromto= $('#vehicledatefrom').val() ;



   After debugging with break point, the datefrom value is = " July 2006";
   But when I am calling the val() in jquery I am getting only "July".
   What's the wrong in my code why I am not getting complete value "July 2006";
   val() is not taking after the space why any suggestions thanks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have not enclosed the `value` attribute using `quotes`.

And it seems to taking only the first part of the value before it is encountering a space which it thinks is the end of it.